# SQLite group datetime by 168 hours (7 days) gives NULL back

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have an `Orders` table in my SQLite database. What I want to do is group by the data by every 168 hours (7 days), and count to total `Orders` per 168 hours.

What I did was create an in memory "calendar table" and I joined my `Orders` table to that calendar set.

This works fine when I group by 12, 24, 48 or even 120 hours (5 days). But for some reason it doesn't work when I group by 168 hours (7 days). I get `NULL` values back instead of what `count()` should really return.

The following sql code is an example that groups by every 120 hours (5 days).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Orders (
    Id    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Key   TEXT,
    Timestamp TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Orders (Key, Timestamp) VALUES ('k1', '2019-10-01 10:00:23');
INSERT INTO Orders (Key, Timestamp) VALUES ('k2', '2019-10-01 15:45:19');
INSERT INTO Orders (Key, Timestamp) VALUES ('k3', '2019-10-02 17:05:19');
INSERT INTO Orders (Key, Timestamp) VALUES ('k4', '2019-10-03 20:12:19');
INSERT INTO Orders (Key, Timestamp) VALUES ('k5', '2019-10-04 08:49:19');
INSERT INTO Orders (Key, Timestamp) VALUES ('k6', '2019-10-05 11:24:19');
INSERT INTO Orders (Key, Timestamp) VALUES ('k7', '2019-10-07 11:24:19');

WITH RECURSIVE dates(date1) AS (
    VALUES('2019-10-01 00:00:00')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datetime(date1, '+120 hours')
    FROM dates
    WHERE date1 <= '2019-10-29 00:00:00'
)
SELECT date1 as __ddd, d2.* FROM dates AS d1

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(Key) AS OrderKey, 
    datetime((strftime('%s', timestamp) / 432000) * 432000, 'unixepoch') as __interval 
    FROM `Orders` 
    WHERE `Timestamp` >= '2019-09-29T00:00:00.000' 
    GROUP BY __interval  LIMIT 10 
) d2 ON d1.date1 = d2.__interval
```

***Important note:***
If you want to update this code to test it with 168 hours (7 days), then you should do the following:

- Change `+120 hours` to `+168 hours`
- Change `432000` (432000 == 120 hours) to 604800 (604800 == 168 hours)

  - ***note that this number occurs twice, both should be replaced***

Anyone any idea why it stops working properly when I change the sql code to 168 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you change to a 7-day interval, the values in your `dates` CTE don't align with the intervals generated from your `Orders` table. You can fix that by making the `dates` CTE start on a similarly aligned date:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(date1) AS (
    SELECT datetime((strftime('%s', '2019-10-01 00:00:00') / 604800) * 604800, 'unixepoch')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datetime(date1, '+168 hours')
    FROM dates
    WHERE date1 <= '2019-10-29 00:00:00'
)
```

Output:

```
__ddd               OrderKey    __interval
2019-09-26 00:00:00 3           2019-09-26 00:00:00
2019-10-03 00:00:00 4           2019-10-03 00:00:00
2019-10-10 00:00:00 null        null
2019-10-17 00:00:00 null        null
2019-10-24 00:00:00 null        null
2019-10-31 00:00:00 null        null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sZ1WBnEJb1LptmiLUZB1ur/0)